# Void function with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

I'm trying to write a code to check with a pointer of int if a number is even or not.
My code is like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void isEven (int *isFlag, int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        *isFlag = 1;
    } else {
        *isFlag = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num = 4;
    int *isFlag = 0;
    isEven(isFlag, num);
    printf("%d", isFlag);
}
```

But I get segmentation fault and I'm expected to see that `isFlag = 1`, what is the problem in the code? (I know we can do it better but I'm trying to understand pointers)

Comment: `int *isFlag = 0` is your problem. You should allocate memory for an int and assign it to isFlag.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them. `printf("%d", isFlag);` -> `printf("%d", *isFlag);`. That's one of the problems.

Comment: `printf("%d", isFlag)` prints the address of the pointer.

Comment: You use a pointer to write. Tell me where that pointer is pointing to when you write via it and I don't have to tell you why there is a segfault.

Comment: was about to post my answer and then I saw 4 answers, seems like everyone is jumping on the bandwagon ^^ Note that you are declaring isFlag as a ptr, I think dbush's answer reflects the most accurately what you should be doing, along with the other nice explanations

Comment: @Tarik Most likely but not necessarily. It's UB

Comment: @klutt Thanks for your correction. How can we find out when something is UB. Any reference I can turn to? Is there a format string to print the address of a pointer?

Comment: @Tarik To find out what's UB in general, read the C standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf To find the right format string, read the documentation for `printf`.   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ Some cases of UB can also be found in such documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring `isFlag` as a pointer in `main` and setting it to a NULL pointer constant.  You then pass that NULL pointer to `isEven` which attempts to dereference it.    Dereferencing a NULL pointer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in the case causes a crash.

Define `isFlag` as an `int` and pass its address to `isEven`.

```
int main() {
    int num = 4;
    int isFlag;
    isEven(&isFlag, num);
    printf("%d", isFlag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`int *isFlag = 0;` defines `isFlag` to be a pointer to `int` and initializes it to point to “nowhere.” (When the constant `0` is used for a pointer, it means a null pointer, which does not point to any object or function.)

You do not need to create a pointer in your `main` routine for this function. You can define an ordinary `int` with `int isFlag = 0;` and pass the address of the `int` to `isEven` with `isEven(&isFlag, num);`.

`&isFlag` will take the address of `isFlag` and pass it to `isEven`. The `isEven` parameter `int *isFlag` will have the value of that pointer. Even though it has the same name as the `isFlag` in `main`, it is a different object, because it is defined in a different scope (inside the function parameter instead of inside `main`), and it has a different type; it will be a pointer to an `int`. So you use it as `*isFlag` inside `isEven` to access the `int` that it points to.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the problem in the code?

Let your compiler tell you what problems it thinks your code may have, before asking us:

[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/1593077)

If you did that, the compiler would tell you (using gcc as an example):

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:16:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has
type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
   16 |     printf("%d", isFlag);
      |             ~^   ~~~~~~
      |              |   |
      |              int int *
      |             %ls
```

that's not *exactly* why you're getting the segmentation fault, but it does tell you you're treating a pointer-to-an-int as though it was an `int`. That's true for the `printf()`  instruction - but it's true more generally. So, your initialization to `0` is how you would initialize an `int`... as other answers explain, that's not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is that it seems you made a typo because you do not have yet solid knowledge relative to pointers.

In this declaration

```
int *isFlag = 0;
```

you declared a null pointer because it is initialized by integer constant 0. So accessing memory using a null pointer results in undefined behavior.

On the other hand, in this statement

```
printf("%d", isFlag);
```

you are outputting the variable `isFlag` as a variable of the type `int`.

What you need is to declare the variable as indeed having the type `int` and pass it to the function by reference through a pointer to it.

That is the code in main will look like

```
int main( void ) {
    int num = 4;
    int isFlag = 0;
    isEven( &isFlag, num );
    printf("%d", isFlag);
}
```

Also the function `isEven` could be defined simpler

```
void isEven( int *isFlag, int num ) {
    *isFlag = num % 2 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems that everyone has summed up.

If you still want to stick to your example (you shouldn't, prefer [dbush's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66822796/3161139)), you can still achieve it the following way, by allocating memory to the ptr:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void isEven (int *isFlag, int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        *isFlag = 1;
    } else {
        *isFlag = 0;
    }
}
int main() {
    int num = 4;
    int *isFlag;

    isFlag = malloc(sizeof(int));
    isEven(isFlag, num);
    printf("%d\n", *isFlag); // also use *isFlag to print the value at ptr's address
    printf("%p\n", isFlag); // print isFlag's address
}
```